# Scrolling a modal like position:absolute, but appearing on the page like postion:fixed

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, primeng

I have a PrimeNG dialog appear on my screen when I user clicks a button.

```
<app-my-modal> [isVisible]="displayModal" [isEdit]="false" (onClose)="hideModalDialog()"></app-my-modal>

<p-dialog
[visible]="isVisible"
[modal]="true"
styleClass="my-modal"
[baseZIndex]="10000"
[draggable]="false"
[resizable]="false"
[closable]="false" >
<p-header>
  {{headerText}}
</p-header>
```

```
.my-modal {
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Once the dialog appears, I want the modal to scroll along with the page. I can do this with position:absolute as I have it. However, no matter where the user is scrolled to in the page, I want the modal to appear in the middle of the screen whenever it pops up. This seems tricky as position:absolute only seems to care about the position relative to the scope of the parent component, whereas I'd need position:fixed to put it in the middle of the page. Is there a way to have in encompass the functionality of both of these?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the way I think I'm going to do it: using [positionTop] to map to window.scrollY

```
<p-dialog
[visible]="isVisible"
[modal]="true"
[positionTop]="topPosition | async"
styleClass="my-modal"
[baseZIndex]="10000"
[draggable]="false"
[resizable]="false"
[closable]="false" >
<p-header>
  {{headerText}}
</p-header>
```

Then my JS will have something like

```
  public topPosition = new Subject<number>();

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll() {
    this.topPosition.next(window.scrollY + 65);
  }
```

This seems inefficient, but it's giving me the result I'm looking for.